# Как добавить объект в массив в json-server/ axios в react

Tags: javascript, json

```
"usersData": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "email": "test1@mail.ru",
      "password": "qwerty1",
      "name": "John Smith",
      "image": "image/photoUser.png",
      "friends": []
    }
]
```

как добавить объект в массив friends через json-server и axios

Comment: прочитайте последнюю часть из [getting-started](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#getting-started)

Comment: @nörbörnën можете мне помочь? я раз десять перечитал не понял

Comment: эм... а так: Если вы сделаете POST, PUT, PATCH или DELETE запросы, изменения будут автоматически и безопасно сохранены в файле db.json

Comment: @nörbörnën я пишу axios.post('http://localhost:3001/usersData?id=0/friends', obj) но так не работает   let obj = {name: "Petya", age: 18}

Comment: в [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#routes) написано про роутинг. а через сервисы яндекса и google даже можно перевести документацию на доступный язык